# @OneToOne replacing entities

Tags: java, hibernate, one-to-one

I have `@OneToOne` bidirectional relationship where parent (`P`) class has:

```
@OneToOne(optional = true, mappedBy = "owner", orphanRemoval = true)
@Cascade({org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.ALL})
```

on getter and child class (`C`) has on getter:

```
@ForeignKey(name = "fk_reference_owner")
@MapsId("owner")
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumns({
        @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "owner_oid", referencedColumnName = "oid"),
        @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "owner_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
})
```

Abbreviations:

`P(<it's primary key>)`

`C(<it's primary key, and it's also FK to P>, <another PK>)`

Situation looks like this:

I have `P(1)` and `C(1, a)` persisted in database - and `C(1, a)` is owned by `P(1)`. Now somewhere in code I create detached instances of `P(1)` and `C(1, a)`. When I call `session.merge(p)` then all properties are merged and after `session.commit()` they are updated. But when I change `C(1, a)`  on detached object to for example `C(1, b)` then `C(1, a)` is not deleted, only `C(1, b)` is persisted. I know it's because that `C(1, b)` doesn't exist in database and hibernate didn't get clear instruction to delete `C(1, a)` - but it should be probably automatic because of `@OneToOne`. Later it fails because of broken `@OneToOne` relationship. I know one of possible solutions is set `P.setC(null)` on attached object. But it's not possible in my case. In time of merging I already have "updated" detached object `P`.

Can I set child to null somewhere during merging with use of custom tuplizer or something like that?

Do you have any ideas how this could be done?

Answer (score 0):

You have a bidirectional association, but one side declares it as a `OneToOne`, and the other side (the owning side) declares it as a `ManyToOne`.

If it's a OneToOne, it should be OneToOne on both sides. If it's a OneTomany, it should be OneToMany on one side and ManyToOne on the other side.

Comment: when I change `ManyToOne` to `OneToOne` I get `Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Foreign key (FKD57C55F9BEABB43A:m_reference [owner_id,owner_oid,target_id,target_oid])) must have same number of columns as the referenced primary key (m_container [id,oid])`

Comment: If I chage it to `OneToOne` an unique key for owner_id,owner_oid is generated. Can't have unique key like that and I didn't find a way to disable that unique key.

Answer (score 0):

Why exactly do you want to change the detached object, when the instance of C(1, a) you have in P(1) is not the one you've created, but a new one, from the persistent context. Perhaps you want to update your reference to C(1, a) to the new, persisted one, and make your changes on it?

Comment: can't do that. Changes are applied on business objects, therefore I always get new state of object. Than I translate this object to my mapped entity classes. That's why it sometimes happen that instance P(1) which previously contained C(1,a) now contains C(1,b). I don't know what exactly changed and therefore I use session.merge().